# How to add HTML code to a different HTML file using JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Alrighty, so I am trying to make a little page on my website that takes a few values and then when you click a button, it adds those values inside of a div on a different HTML page.

My code is:

```
<input type="text" name="URL"><br>
<input type="text" name="ImageURL"><br>
<input type="text" name="Title">
<button onclick="addCode()">Submit</button>
```

So for the addCode() function I want it so that it adds the values inside of a the item div on a different HTML file just like:

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="animate-box">
      <a href=URL><img src=ImageURL></a>                
      <div class="fh5co-desc"><a style="TEXT-DECORATION:none; COLOR:#818892; LINE-HEIGHT:20px;" href=URL>Title</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript on one page is not available when you load a new page. This should be done with a dynamic server side programming language that processes the form data and outputs associated content...... unless you intend to ajax load the other page and instert it into current page

Comment: @charlietfl See my answer below. It can be done in the right circumstances.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do here.

Comment: @RobertMoskal I want to have a few <input> elements which take a URL, an image URL and a title. I want that to then be added to a different html file, with the values that were entered.

Comment: Create an `index.php` file with a `form` containing `input` fields and `submit` button. Set `action='second_page.php'`. Receive by the name of the input field, at the start of code, the data submitted: For example, `if(isset($_POST['Title'])){ echo $_POST['Title']; }`. If you can display it there, then PHP can easily be written with HTML embedded in it to help you achieve what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this (without getting other technologies involved) is to use the `localStorage`, **[`storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage)** event. And, even with this, it will only work when the two pages are coming from the same domain and are open in different browser tabs (of the same browser) at the same time.

If those conditions are present, then modifying `localStorage` on one page will fire the `storage` event, which the other page can be set up to listen for. The other page can then respond to the event by pulling new values (that the first page wrote into `localStorage`) out and placing them anywhere on the second page that you like.

This is the kind of solution that you might encounter if you were on a travel site with more than one browser tab open. You may be looking at different flight options in different tabs. If one tab's code has an update that any/all other open tabs should know about, this technique does the trick.

Here's an example of how to set values into `localStorage` and use them. But, `localStorage` doesn't work here in the Stack Overflow snippet environment, so you can run the code **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/m5e6u1av/1/)**.

Once the values are in `localStorage`, you can pick them up from any other page that is being served from the same domain. So, the "getItem" code I'm showing here would really be placed on your "page2.html".

```js
// Get DOM references:
var name = document.getElementById("name");
var color = document.getElementById("color");
var airspeed = document.getElementById("airspeed");
var btn = document.getElementById("btnGo");

// Set up button click event handler:
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

  // Get values and place in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("name", name.value);
  localStorage.setItem("color", color.value);
  localStorage.setItem("airspeed", airspeed.value); 
  
  // For demonstration, get values out of localStorage
  console.log("What is your name? ", localStorage.getItem("name"));
  console.log("What is your favorite color? ", localStorage.getItem("color"));
  console.log("What is the airspeed of a laiden swallow? ", localStorage.getItem("airspeed"));  
  
  // If you wanted to redirect the user to the second page, now that the intial values
  // have been set, you could just do:
  location.href = "path to second page";
  
});
```

```html
<div>What is your name?<input type="text" id="name"></div>
<div>What is your favorite color?<input type="text" id="color"></div>
<div>What is the airspeed of a laiden swallow?<input type="text" id="airspeed"></div>
<button id="btnGo">Go!</button>
```

Comment: don't have to be different tabs...not sure why that is mentioned as requirement

Comment: Because the storage event isn't really useful without multiple tabs. If we're talking about a single page, then you know when you are modifying localstorage and don't need an event handler for it.

Comment: Hmm, I might be able to do this. But is there a way to do it with PHP that you know of?

Comment: or store the data...then redirect...load data in new page

Comment: Once you add a server-side technology, there are numerous ways to do this.

Comment: @charlietfl Sure, but you don't need the storage event to do that and that isn't what the OP is asking for.

Comment: depends on interpretation of what op is asking which certainly could use clarification

Comment: @charlietfl that seems like a plausible solution, how can I do that?

Comment: @ScottMarcus how do I make it so that it takes the localStorage and adds code to the second page?

Comment: @Gavwin For example, take the 3 lines that use `localStorage.getItem(...)` from my example above and use them in page 2 to extract the values and then you can use them anywhere in the second page that you need them.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is technically impossible. without some sort of persistence, that is;

you cannot edit a page you aren't on. web browsing is a stateless technology.

if you meant you want to fill out those inputs then redirect on click and have those values available, there are a few different ways to do it:

1) Query String

write your code on the second page in a way that it accepts params from a query string in the url bar

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
}

var textDecoration = getUrlParameter('textdec'),
    color = getUrlParameter('color'),
    lineHeight = getUrlParameter('lnheight');
```

then you can send the request for the page as

`http://page.com/page?textdec="someval"&color="somecolor"&lnheight="someheight"`

however this will not work if you are not going directly to that page after your current one

2) localStorage

on your first page set the local storage values:

```
localStorage.setItem('lineHeight', 'someVal');
localStorage.setItem('color', 'someColor');
localStorage.setItem('textDecoration', 'someVal');
```

then on your second page retrieve the values

```
var lineHeight = localStorage.getItem('lineHeight'),
    color = localStorage.getItem('color'),
    textDecoration = localStorage.getItem('textDecoration');
```

3) serverSide persistence

this will vary MASSIVELY depending on how you your backend is structured

but the general gist is make a post request (ajax or otherwise) &
collect the data on the backend

then when you render the second page send the variables that were posted, either through interpolation or included as script variables

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to edit the actual source code of the file, you'll need something like PHP.  Otherwise, JS is just fine.

---

## PHP Solution

You could use something like this:

```html
<?php
$old = file_get_contents("some_page.html");
$content = explode("<span>",$old,2); // replace <span> w/ opening tag
$content = explode("</span>",$content[1],2); // replace </span> w/ closing tag
$data = "new content of element";
$new = str_replace($content[0],$data,$old);
?>
```

## Updated JS Solution

You can't use my previous solution.  Instead, you would have to create a function in the second HTML file that could be called from the first file, like this:
A script in file2.html:

```js
function set(id,val){
    $("#"+id).html(val); // jQuery
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val; // pure JS
}
```

A script in file1.html:

```js
var win = window.open("http://example.com"); // open the window
win.set("some_id","Some content.") // the function that we set earlier
```

Note that this is reverted once the user closes or reloads the tab, and only applies to that user and that tab.

Comment: How could I do it with PHP?

Comment: @Gavwin Are you sure about what Leo is asking you? Dropping values into a second file that came from the first isn't a permanent change? Leo is asking you if the source code file (the .html file) will be modified for good on the server's file system. I don't think that is what you have described.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I guess not.. Thanks for explaining what he said.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I interpreted the question the same way that you did, hence my first solution.  You're entirely correct.

Comment: @Gavwin Sorry for any confusion :)

Comment: @LeoWilson It's alright! I just misread your comment. I'm a bit tired right now.